# conditionally setting value of the passing parameter to template

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am calling a template with some parameters, and one of them I need to set it conditionally. According to some documentation this is supposed to work:

```
- template: _task.generateresourcegroupname.yml
      parameters: 
        environment: ${{ if and(eq(parameters.deployToDev, true), eq(parameters.deployToTest, false)) }} dev ${{ else }} prod
        rgVariableName: resourceGroupName
        appName: App2
        appVersion: '01'
        filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Pipelines/scripts/GenerateResourceGroupName.ps1'
```

but it doesn't. I get an error, "The directive 'if' is not allowed in this context. Directives are not supported for expressions that are embedded within a string. Directives are only supported when the entire value is an expression.".

Can the syntax such as this, an a single line, work? Or it need to be expanded in multiple lines? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, Azure DevOps doesn't support the single line if expression.

To solve this issue, you need to change the following format in the YAML file.

```
- template: _task.generateresourcegroupname.yml
  parameters:
   ${{ if and(eq(parameters.deployToDev, true), eq(parameters.deployToTest, false)) }}:
    environment: dev 
   ${{ else }}:
    environment: prod
```

Then the value will be set based on the parameters value.

Full Yaml example:

```
parameters:
  - name: deployToDev
    type: string
    default: true
  - name: deployToTest
    type: string
    default: true
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- template: _task.generateresourcegroupname.yml
  parameters:
   ${{ if and(eq(parameters.deployToDev, true), eq(parameters.deployToTest, false)) }}:
    environment: dev 
   ${{ else }}:
    environment: prod
   rgVariableName: resourceGroupName
   appName: App2
   appVersion: '01'
   filePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Pipelines/scripts/GenerateResourceGroupName.ps1'
```